# A question related to an inequality involving a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions, meromorphic-functions

I'm trying to solve the following problem from one of the past qualifying exams.

> Find an explicit formula for all meromorphic functions $g$ on
> $\mathbb{C}$ such that $$|g(z)|\leq \frac{\log(2+|z|^2)}{|z|}$$ for
> all $z\neq 0$.

I am completely stumped on how to start on this problem. I tried using Laurent expansion, but it's not getting me anywhere. Any hint/help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: note that $zg(z)$ is entire and is logarithmically bounded at infinity which easily implies by Cauchy (coefficient by coefficient) or Parseval (that does it in one swoop) that is constant

Comment: @Conrad Thank you, that makes a lot of sense!